# How can I choose left or right bottom builtin microphone while recording in iOS?

Tags: ios, microphone, avaudiosession

I just followed [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1799/_index.html)
doc and tried to record audio. For iPhone 6s and above devices, which have two mics at the bottom, I get the same kind of data source supports as mentioned below.

```
"<AVAudioSessionDataSourceDescription: 0x14d93800, ID = 1835216945; name = Bottom>",
"<AVAudioSessionDataSourceDescription: 0x14d938d0, ID = 1835216946; name = Front>",
"<AVAudioSessionDataSourceDescription: 0x14d93a10, ID = 1835216947; name = Back>"
```

By these, I can just set the orientation to Bottom, Front, and Back. Can I set orientation to left/right so that I can record through those two separately?

!!! I have this question because **Apple** has introduced **AVAudioSessionOrientationLeft** and **AVAudioSessionOrientationRight** long back, with iOS 8. And not deprecated yet.

Comment: I am also interested on knowing this. I tried device orientation and speak on the bottom microphone and still its returning only the left channel bytes.